# python regex keep text between the last two occurrences of a character

Tags: python, regex

As the title says, I want to extract the text between the last two ocurrences of a character in a string.

I have:

```
'9500 anti-Xa IU/ml - 0,6 ml 5700 IU -'
'120 mg/ml – 0.165 ml -'
'300-300-300 IR/ml  or  IC/ml - 10 ml -'
'Fluocortolone-21-pivalate 1 mg/g, Lidocaine hydrochloride 20 mg/g - 15 g -'
```

I want to have:

```
'0,6 ml 5700 IU'
'0.165 ml'
'10 ml'
'15 g'
```

I tried using `-\s*.*-` but it matches everything between first and last `-`. What's the correct regex to use?

Comment: you could use `split('-')` and get item `[-2]` from list of results. But problem can be you have two different chars: short `-` and long `–`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With search:

```
import re
[re.search(r'[-–]\s*([^-–]+?)\s*[-–][^-–]*$', x).group(1) for x in l]
```

Or split:

```
[re.split(r'\s+[-–]\s*', x, 2)[-2] for x in l]
```

output: `['0,6 ml 5700 IU', '0.165 ml', '10 ml', '15 g']`

used input:

```
l = ['9500 anti-Xa IU/ml - 0,6 ml 5700 IU -',
     '120 mg/ml – 0.165 ml -',
     '300-300-300 IR/ml  or  IC/ml - 10 ml -',
     'Fluocortolone-21-pivalate 1 mg/g, Lidocaine hydrochloride 20 mg/g - 15 g -'
    ]
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f9vPHq/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[^-–—\s][^-–—]*?(?=\s*[-–—][^-–—]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oNl2nn/1). *Details*:

- `[^-–—\s]` - a char other than whitespace, `-`, `–` and `—`
- `[^-–—]*?` - zero or more chars other than `-`, `–` and `—` as few as possible
- `(?=\s*[-–—][^-–—]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespaces, then a `-`, `–` or `—` char and then zero or more chars other than `-`, `–` and `—` till end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples Only. Please try following regex with Python code, written and tested in Python3. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/QETRrK/1) for used regex.

```
import re

var="""9500 anti-Xa IU/ml - 0,6 ml 5700 IU -
120 mg/ml - 0.165 ml -
300-300-300 IR/ml  or  IC/ml - 10 ml -
Fluocortolone-21-pivalate 1 mg/g, Lidocaine hydrochloride 20 mg/g - 15 g -"""

[x.strip(' ') for x in re.findall(r'(?<=\s-|\s–)(.*?)(?=-)',var,re.M)]
```

Output will be as follows:

```
['0,6 ml 5700 IU', '0.165 ml', '10 ml', '15 g']
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using Python3's `re` module's [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall) function. Where I am using regex `r'(?<=\s-|\s–)(.*?)(?=-)'` to get the required output. Then removing all leading and trailing spaces with `strip` function from it to get expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to also match the blank space before the last dash `-`:

`\s\-\s(.*)\s\-`

By the way, maybe [regex101 website](https://regex101.com/r/lcBKpp/1) could help you next time you have a new regex issue.

**EDIT**

I just see that you have two types of dash symbols! Short `-` and long `–`. Try this regex instead:

`\s[-–]\s(.*)\s[-–]`